# How to change android app bar default elevation?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

I want to increase or decrease the app bar layout elevation. Currently I am using this code:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

This works if app elevation is 0dp. Elevation is removed. But I don't want to completely remove it. I want to alter the value of app bar default elevation.

Answer (score 0):

The default elevation for the app bar is 4dp, as stated in the [material design docs](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#default-elevations)
You can increase or decrease the elevation by changing the 4dp value.

To set the elevation in XML you'll need to call.

```
android:elevation="4dp"
```

To set the elevation programmatically you want to call `setElevation()` on the appBar.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar#setElevation(float)

Comment: Not working for me